# On what site would I ask questions about text messaging?

Tags: discussion

I have a samsung magnet phone which is a blackberry-esque phone that predates smartphones. I have a question concerning text messaging on my phone and current text messaging features and platforms. What site is appropriate to ask this type of question?

Comment: sadly enough, there's no real site - the late consumer electronics SE site (which never got out of beta) might have been the place for this

Comment: Hm. Thanks for the insight. Can I ask this on the Androids site or that's strictly for smartphones and their OS's?

Comment: @ChristopherChipps The Samsung Magnet is not an Android OS device, so your question would be off-topic on http://android.stackexchange.com/ . However, seeing as how Samsung's Android devices are very popular, you might be able to get a hold of a longtime Samsung phone owner in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android) who may be of help!

Comment: @iglvzx Much appreciated for the heads up about the Androids site. Will have to look into the chatroom, thanks again!

Comment: Seems like there's another proposal http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you should try to perform the text messaging itself through your PC, then it's cool for Super User.

Otherwise, I don't see any open site that would be a good fit.